# Python, evaluation output of OS command in an if statement

Tags: python, shell

I want to convert the following shell evaluation to python2.6(can't upgrade). I can't figure out how to evaluate the output of the command.

Here's the shell version:

```
status=`$hastatus -sum |grep $hostname |grep Grp| awk '{print $6}'`
if [ $status != "ONLINE" ]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

I tried `os.popen` and it returns ['ONLINE\n'].

```
value = os.popen("hastatus -sum |grep `hostname` |grep Grp| awk '{print $6}'".readlines()
print value
```

Comment: So … it's the same?

Comment: The shell version returns just "ONLINE", the os.popen returns "['ONLINE\n']". That's fine, but I don't know how to test it against "ONLINE"

Comment: `if 'ONLINE' is in value: ....`

Answer (score 0):

Try the subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
value = subprocess.call("hastatus -sum |grep `hostname` |grep Grp| awk '{print $6}'")
print(value)
```

Documentation is found here:
https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#module-subprocess

Comment: Thanks, but the pipe seems to get ignored. The documentation shows commands and arguments (["command", "args"]) I can't find a pipe equivalent.

Comment: You could wrap your shell command in a shell script.  That would be easily callable through this, then. Not sure is that defeats what you are trying to do, though.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.
The following section of the documentation is instructive:
[replacing shell pipeline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline)
I report here for reference:

> output=`dmesg | grep hda`

becomes:

> `p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)`
>
> `p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)`
> `p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.`
> `output = p2.communicate()[0]`
>
> The `p1.stdout.close()` call after starting the `p2` is important in order for `p1` to receive a `SIGPIPE` if `p2` exits before `p1`.
>
> Alternatively, for trusted input, the shell’s own pipeline support may still be used directly:
>
> output=`dmesg | grep hda`

becomes:

> `output=check_output("dmesg | grep hda", shell=True)`

And here the recipe to translate os.popen to the subprocess module:
[replacing os.popen()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3)

So in your case you could do something like

```
import subprocess

output=check_output("hastatus -sum |grep `hostname` |grep Grp| awk '{print $6}'", shell=True)
```

or

concatenating the Popens as showed in the documentation above (probably what I would do).

Then to test the output you could just use, assuming you're using the first approach:

```
import sys
import subprocess

....
if 'ONLINE' in output:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's just easier for me to do it in shell for now.